# Get Jasmine test reporter output into a specified page element

Tags: javascript, testing, jasmine

I'm trying to get the Jasmine output into a specified element in my test runner HTML file, and haven't found a way to control this.  Buried in the TrivialReporter code is

```
this.document.body.appendChild(this.outerDiv);
```

and the constructor allows one to set the `this.document` element, but any element you pass in would need a `.body`.

Have I missed something obvious?

Answer (score 1):

A workaround: move the results element after a few millis..

Pop a `<div id="move_results_to_here"></div>` in where the reporter output needs to go, then:

```
window.setTimeout(function(){
    $(".jasmine_reporter").appendTo("#move_results_to_here");
}, 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed something similar with the following jQuery code:

```
$('.jasmine_reporter').wrap('<div id="unitTestsContainer" />');
```

Then I wrote CSS rules for #unitTestsContainer. Using this code, I was able to put the Jasmine output into a dismissible popover/overlay window (built with jQuery UI).

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that the above line of code was in a function execJasmine, which first calls jasmineEnv.execute();

Answer (score 0):

I came across this question because the Jasmine reports were ending up at the bottom of the page, and I wanted them to be immediately visible without scrolling. Also I didn't care about the other content on the page. If that describes your situation, try adding this CSS to your page:

```
.jasmine_html-reporter {
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 99999;
}
```